# Modus Barbara, Modus Celarent, et Modus Darii: (Modi Barbara, Celarent, et Darii)?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, medieval-latin, history, logic, philosophy-terms

Modus Barbara, Modus Celarent, and Modus Darii are names of valid syllogisms in the medieval taxonomy of valid syllogisms. I'm wondering how to say: "Moduses Barbara, Celarent, and Darii." As far as I'm capable, "Modi Barbara, Celarent, et Darii" is all that I can come up with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those unfamiliar with this terminology, this question refers to medieval mnemonic names for syllogisms, mostly drawn from Aristotelian logic. All valid syllogisms, along with their names, are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism).

The names "Barbara," "Celarent," and "Darii" (as well as the fourth first figure mood which you seem to have left out: "Ferio") are obviously indeclinable, since their vowels refer to the four types of propositions: A, E, I, and O (universal/particular affirmation/negation).

If you wish to translate your phrase as-is, you are correct to add the terms in apposition after *modi*. I found one precedent for this construction in a [logic manual](https://books.google.com/books?id=mrJfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA306):

> Non minus contorta vulgo est argumentandi ratio, si syllogismi tertiae figurae, qui sunt **in modis Disamis atque Bocardo** ad primam figuram reducuntur.

I therefore think your translation is correct:

> **Modi Barbara, Celarent, et Darii**

This is a little awkward. If you can reword, it might be easier to understand if you separated them out a little:

> Hi sunt modi primae figurae: Barbara, Celarent, Darii, et Ferio. Modus Barbara est...etc.